# Which statement is more idiomatic, or they all have grammar mistakes

Tags: word-choice

1.Here are two pictures, if you use **the small one** to compare with the **big one**, you will find some differences.

3.Here are two pictures, if you use **the smaller one** to compare with the **bigger one**, you will find some differences.

2.Here are two pictures, if you use **the smaller one** to compare with the **big one**, you will find some differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Use X to compare with Y* is awkward and unidiomatic. Natural ways to express this are

> ... if you compare X with Y ... *or*
>   ... if you compare X to Y ... *or*
>   ... if you compare X and Y ...

With that change, any of the expressions for *X* and *Y* will work; but by and large it makes easier for the reader if the two elements are cast in the same form, either the base or the comparative:

> ... if you compare the **big** one with/to/and the **small** one ...
>   ... if you compare the **bigger** (one) with/to/and the **smaller** (one)

*One* is usually required with the base form, because *the +  ADJ<sub>baseform</sub>* usually means not a specific *ADJ* individual but all *ADJ* persons or things; but *one* is optional with the comparative form.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we use small and large for pictures:
**The big picture** also **the whole picture**
It means the most important facts about a situation and the effects that it has on other things.
Example: In my political work I try to concentrate on the big picture and not to be distracted by details.
You can use:

> 1.Here are two pictures, if you use the small one to compare with the big one, you will find some differences.

But it is better to use instead:
Here are two pictures, if you compare the small one to the large one, you will find some differences.

Also for the second sentence, you can use:

> 2.Here are two pictures, if you use the smaller one to compare with the bigger one, you will find some differences.

But it is better to say:
Here are two pictures, if you compare the smaller one to the largest one, you will find some differences.

> 3.Here are two pictures, if you use the smaller one to compare with the big one, you will find some differences.

This third sentence has definitely grammar mistakes, both adjectives should be the same:

- Small with large
- Smallest with largest